# Битрикс: дублирование заказов, при массовом создании

Tags: php, битрикс

Задача загружать заказы в бд. Их может быть как 1 так и 21 и 51 за раз, кол-во разное.

Что сделал:
Получаю информацию о заказах (кол-во разное от 1 до 1000).
Обрабатываю данные, подготавливаю массив.
Далее в цикле, поштучно запускаю функцию создания заказов.
И тут возникает проблема:
если заказов до 15-18шт, они создаются без проблем, если кол-во больше то происходит дублирование заказов, причем такое ощущение, что цикл выполняется дважды, один и тот же заказ создается дважды.

```
public static function getPosting()
{
    //тут получаем данные о заказах, подготавливаем $orders

    $ids = array();
    foreach ($orders as $ord) {
        $co = Orderlib::createOrder($ord);
        $ids[] = $co;
    }

    echo "<pre>"; print_r($ids); echo "</pre>";
}


public static function createOrder($o)
{
    $siteId = Context::getCurrent()->getSite();
    $currencyCode = Option::get('sale', 'default_currency', 'RUB');

    $basket = Basket::create($siteId);

    foreach ($o['products'] as $product) {

        $item = $basket->createItem("catalog", $product["offer_id"]);
        $item->setFields(array(
           'PRODUCT_PROVIDER_CLASS' => '\Bitrix\Catalog\Product\CatalogProvider',
           'NAME' => $product["name"],
           'PRICE' => $product["price"],
           'CURRENCY' => $currencyCode,
           'QUANTITY' => $product["quantity"],
        ));
        $item->markFieldCustom('PRICE');
        $item->setField('PRICE', $product["price"]);
    }

    $order = Order::create($siteId, Setting::UserId);

    $personTypeId = Setting::PersonTypeId;
    $order->setPersonTypeId($personTypeId);
    $order->setBasket($basket);

    //служба доставки
    $deliveryId = Setting::DeliveryMethod[$o['delivery_method_id']];
    $shipmentCollection = $order->getShipmentCollection();
    $shipment = $shipmentCollection->createItem(
        Delivery\Services\Manager::getObjectById($deliveryId)
    );

    $shipmentItemCollection = $shipment->getShipmentItemCollection();
    foreach ($basket as $basketItem) {
        $item = $shipmentItemCollection->createItem($basketItem);
        $item->setQuantity($basketItem->getQuantity());
    }

    //платежная система
    $paymentCollection = $order->getPaymentCollection();
    $payment = $paymentCollection->createItem(
        PaySystem\Manager::getObjectById(Setting::PaySystemId)
    );

    $payment->setField("SUM", $order->getPrice());
    $payment->setField("CURRENCY", $order->getCurrency());

    //свойства заказа
    $propertyCollection = $order->getPropertyCollection();
    foreach ($propertyCollection as $item) {
      //заполняем свойства заказа
    }

    $order->setField('DATE_INSERT', self::getDateFormatSite($o['in_process_at']));
    $order->setField('STATUS_ID', Setting::StatusDefaultID);
    $order->setField('CURRENCY', $currencyCode);

    $ord_id = 0;

    $r = $order->save();
    if (!$r->isSuccess()) {
        Loglib::log($o['posting_number'] . ' ' . var_dump($r->getErrorMessages()), Setting::MODULE);
    } else {
        Loglib::log('Заказ ' . $o['posting_number'] . ' создан! Номер заказа ' . $order->getId(), Setting::MODULE);
        $ord_id = $r->GetId();
    }

    return $ord_id;
}
```

Это вывод из функции getPosting. 0-это не дошли до создания заказа, по всяким проверкам. "заказ уже есть в бд" - это была проверка на наличие в бд заказа

```
Array
(
    [0] => Заказ уже есть в бд
    [1] => Заказ уже есть в бд
    [2] => Заказ уже есть в бд
    [3] => Заказ уже есть в бд
    [4] => 0
    [5] => Заказ уже есть в бд
    [6] => Заказ уже есть в бд
    [7] => Заказ уже есть в бд
    [8] => Заказ уже есть в бд
    [9] => Заказ уже есть в бд
    [10] => Заказ уже есть в бд
    [11] => Заказ уже есть в бд
    [12] => Заказ уже есть в бд
    [13] => Заказ уже есть в бд
    [14] => Заказ уже есть в бд
    [15] => Заказ уже есть в бд
    [16] => Заказ уже есть в бд
    [17] => 0
    [18] => Заказ уже есть в бд
    [19] => Заказ уже есть в бд
    [20] => Заказ уже есть в бд
    [21] => Заказ уже есть в бд
    [22] => Заказ уже есть в бд
)
```

А это лог одного из заказов, из которого видно, что форич дважды проходил массив и запускал функцию создания заказа тоже дважды:

```
------------------------------
!!! 29-01-2022 13:24:24 a1
------------------------------
Мы еще в фориче, Попытка создать заказ 55524814-0019-3
------------------------------
!!! 29-01-2022 13:24:24 a1
------------------------------
Запустилась функция создания заказа 55524814-0019-3
------------------------------
!!! 29-01-2022 13:24:24 a1
------------------------------
Попытка создать заказ 55524814-0019-3
------------------------------
!!! 29-01-2022 13:24:25 a1
------------------------------
Заказ 55524814-0019-3 создан! Номер заказа 46941



------------------------------
!!! 29-01-2022 13:24:33 a1
------------------------------
Мы еще в фориче, Попытка создать заказ 55524814-0019-3
------------------------------
!!! 29-01-2022 13:24:33 a1
------------------------------
Запустилась функция создания заказа 55524814-0019-3
------------------------------
!!! 29-01-2022 13:24:33 a1
------------------------------
Попытка создать заказ 55524814-0019-3
------------------------------
!!! 29-01-2022 13:24:33 a1
------------------------------
Заказ 55524814-0019-3 в базе данных уже есть!!!
```

Comment: Проверьте, что у вас не запускаются два параллельных процесса обработки заказов.

Comment: @ВикторКарев функция выполнялась при загрузке хтмл страницы, и действительно каким то непонятным для меня образом запускалось два процесса. Запустил в фоновом режиме и все заработало на ура! Спасибо за комментарий!